# Notifications not received on Android device via Azure Notifications hub, but on firebase console they deliver as expected

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have recently updated my app to flutter for cross platform availability but I am having trouble receiving push notifications.

When I send an "alert" to the backend, users should be notified that someone sent out an alert.

Right now when I call the `SendFCMNativeNotificationsAsync` method, I always get an enqueued response (when I only had an Android version they always said successful).

```
private async Task sendNotifAsync(Alert alert)
{
    Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcome outcome = null;
    HttpStatusCode ret = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    var cafe = cafeRepository.GetById(alert.CafeId);
    var message = alert.UserName + " needs help in " + cafe.Name;
    var notif = "{ \"notification\":{\"title\":\"Somebody needs help\",\"body\":\""+message+"\"},\"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + "From " + alert.UserName + ": " + message + "\"}}";
    outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif);
}
```

This is the code I use to call the `notificationhub` in my backend.

The weird thing is that when I try to send a test notification via firebase console, it works as expected, so I don't really know where to look right now to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To send push notification to a Flutter application targeting **Android** and **iOS**, first we need to handle **device registration** for the client using the latest and best **Installation** approach using an `ASP.NET` Core Web API backend. Check this [Registration management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) document more further details.

There can be many reasons why you are facing this issue, it may be due to **Notification Hubs misconfiguration** or may be for **Application issue** due to invalid registration and **Push notification service** could also be the issues.

Since you are getting notification from firebase console, push notification service should not be an issue. Still you can use the `EnableTestSend` property while you initialize `NotificationHubClient` to get a detailed status about push notification service errors that occur if any when the notification is sent.

```cs
bool enableTestSend = true;
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connString, hubName, enableTestSend);

var outcome = await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
Console.WriteLine(outcome.State);

foreach (RegistrationResult result in outcome.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ApplicationPlatform + "\n" + result.RegistrationId + "\n" + result.Outcome);
}
```

I would suggest to read the [Diagnose dropped notifications in Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) document from Microsoft to do some self-diagnosis and solve the problem you are facing. Also read the [Send push notifications to Flutter apps using Azure Notification Hubs via a backend service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-flutter) document for more information.